# read an input text file and strore the tokens in 2 different arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am very new to java so please ignore if there are obvious mistakes. If my question seems redundant then please guide me towards the correct link. However, I have surfed enough in order to find the answer.
I am reading an input file and storing the elements of it in a 2D array. What I want to do is split that array in 2 separate arrays. 1st array would contain all the characters which is "firstDimension" in my code. Now, i want another array which stores all the integers in an array. I just have to print those arrays. This array should be created as soon as the special character '>' is observed.
This can be done in 2 ways:

1. Read the strings in the file and store all of the elements in a 2D array and then divide the array into 1 double and one 2D char array
2. Read only chars from the file and store it in char array and then read only double values from the file and store it in different array.

my input file has text:

> ```
> a A b u>0.0001
> b b X g>0.0005
> Y z N H>0.0003
> ```

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Delimiter {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("hello.txt"));
            scanner.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                list.add(scanner.next());
            }
            scanner.close();

            // finally convert the arraylist to a char[][]
            char[][] firstDimension = new char[list.size()][];
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                firstDimension[i] = list.get(i).toCharArray();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < firstDimension.length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < firstDimension[i].length; j++)
                {
                    //System.out.println(firstDimension[i][j]);
                    System.out.print(" "+firstDimension[i][j]);
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i just added the code

Comment: So.. What is the question?

Comment: question is how do i split the array in 2 separate arrays. 1st array containing all the characters and the second containing all the double values.

Comment: Any changes in code would be greatly appreciated. Please help me if you can.

Comment: [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) <- is that way.

Comment: I am sorry. I din't get you.

Comment: Do i paste the same question there?

Comment: If you want folks to read through your working code and tell you whether there's a better way to write it, you should post it on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of here. If you need help understanding how to use a language feature or algorithm, this is the place.

Comment: Can you please explain how should I make it work if you cant make the changes. I will go ahead and add this in Code review too.

Comment: I think that i have to use string split method. But for that Do I have to split use the ArrayList containing the strings parsed from the file before inserting into the array. Or is there any way to parse the characters in the array and split it into 2 arrays

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are any methods that do this for you, but you could say

```
if(var == 0 || 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 ) //all the way until you reach 9
{
      //is a number and needs to be put in the double array
}
else //is a string
```

- EDIT

Since you're storing the data in an array, you may have to use the BinarySearch method.